# Query blocking entirely MySQL server

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to a run a specific query. However, when I execute it, the MySQL server doesn't respond anymore.

There is approximately 30000 rows in the table `base_contrats_actifs` but I don't know if this is a problem.

Here is the query :

```
UPDATE
  base_contrats_actifs a
SET
  a.code_indice = (
    SELECT
      MAX(g.code_indice)
    FROM
      base_gid g
    WHERE
      a.num_version = g.num_version_contrat
  ),
  a.flag_bailleur_locataire = (
    SELECT
      MAX(g.flag_bailleur_locataire)
    FROM
      base_gid g
    WHERE
      a.num_version = g.num_version_contrat
  ),
  a.compte_client = (
    SELECT
      MAX(g.compte_client)
    FROM
      base_gid g
    WHERE
      a.num_version = g.num_version_contrat
  )
```

Can you see if there is an error ? If not, is there any way to debug the query ?

Comment: The syntax is fine. Probably the server is busy executing your update.

Comment: Any triggers involved?

Comment: I don't know what a trigger is so they are probably not involved @jarlh .

Comment: How long does the query take when you replace the first three lines with a `select` clause, making it a query and not an update statement?

Comment: I can't really say as there is a set statement @cars10m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly why your update is non performant, but given the number of correlated subqueries you have, I'm not surprised.  Try rewriting it as an update join:

```
UPDATE base_contrats_actifs a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        num_version_contrat,
        MAX(code_indice)             AS max_code_indice,
        MAX(flag_bailleur_locataire) AS max_flag_bailleur_locataire,
        MAX(compte_client)           AS max_compte_client
    FROM base_gid
    GROUP BY num_version_contrat
) g
    ON a.num_version = g.num_version_contrat
SET
    a.code_indice             = g.max_code_indice,
    a.flag_bailleur_locataire = g.max_flag_bailleur_locataire,
    a.compte_client           = g.max_compte_client;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! the g alias was not recognized by the server any idea why ?

Comment: Reload your page, I made a few minor edits since I posted, and possibly since you reloaded your page.

Comment: It still says that g.code_indice is an unknown field

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it.  The problem was in the subquery.

Comment: Please don't be sorry you saved my day ! It work in 13 second. So if I understand correctly joining the table is actually faster ?

Comment: Apparently so.  The thing with the correlated subqueries, is that you're forcing MySQL to issue _three_ queries for _each_ row in the table being updated.  As all the tables involved get large, this can become a huge penalty.  Some database optimizers are smart enough to internally rewrite the update to what I wrote in my answer, but maybe not in this case, for MySQL.

Comment: Nice ! Thank you again, I saw a lot of inner join to optimize query, is it a go to solution when we have problem like this ?

Comment: You have to basically know what to do to make it work reasonably fast.  Sometimes it isn't possible to rewrite correlated subqueries using joins, and in those cases, you're stuck with them.